# Change locale in moment do not refresh vuejs component accordingly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I have a js class, User, with a moment object inside:

```
import moment from 'moment'
class User {
    expirationDate = moment();
}
```

I want to display this date according to the locale of the app. I am using VueJS. To allow an easy access of moment variable inside a Vue component, I have exposed the moment variable:

```
Vue.prototype.$moment = moment;
```

Inside one of my component, I have a button that allow the user to change his locale.

```
this.$moment.locale(newLocale); // newLocale can be en-us, zh-cn, ....
```

But the date is not translated.
To go further, I have inside the same module made the following created function:

```
  created: function() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.$moment.locale());
      console.log(this.user.expirationDate.format('ll'));
      console.log(this.$moment().format('ll'));
    }, 1000);
  }
```

and here is the result

```
UserProfile.vue?ebc3:52 en
UserProfile.vue?ebc3:52 Nov 30, 2018
UserProfile.vue?ebc3:53 Nov 21, 2018
UserProfile.vue?ebc3:51 zh-cn
UserProfile.vue?ebc3:52 Nov 30, 2018
UserProfile.vue?ebc3:53 2018年11月21日
```

So I don't understand why the formatting of my user moment is not working.
I was afraid that the instance of the moment variable was not the same between $moment and the one used in my user.js. So I ended up trying this:

```
console.log(this.$moment(this.user.expirationDate).format('ll'));
```

but the result is the same : no translation at all !
I also added this to my User class:

```
import moment from 'moment'
class User {
    expirationDate = moment();
    constructor(data) {
        setInterval(()=>{console.log('from user.js > ' + moment.locale())}, 1000)
    }
}
```

and notified that the locale is correct. So it doesn't seems to be a variable issues...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Similar problem:

My application have a top bar containing a select input to change the locale. 
When a component is rendered, if I update the locale, the component is not re-rendered so the date format is still the same....

## What's help me find a clean solution

Read [this article](http://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/)

## Solution in practice

Edit the html template of your `AppComponent`, to add this attribute `:key:"language"`, for an example:

```html
<div :key="language">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Then edit your `AppComponent` class:

```js
data: {
    selectedLanguage: 'fr'
},
computed: {
    language: function () {
      return this.selectedLanguage;
    }
}
```

When `selectedLanguage` value will be changed, then the `key` attribute value of the component will changed and will trigger the `AppComponent` re-rendering and its children will also be re-rendered.

To be sure that moment configuration has been updated before the global re-rendering, make sure to call the `this.$moment.locale(newLocale)` method before to update the `selectedLanguage` .

PS:
I have translated this code from my application that use [Vue Property Decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) and [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), please tell me if I have missed something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

i just want to share my solution for whom may needed it.
i'm using vuex to store lang for i18n nothing special here

```
state:{locale:'en'}, //en by default                                                             
getters:{locale: (state) => state.locale,},                                   
mutations: { SET_LOCALE: (state, payload) => {locale = payload|| state.locale;}}                    
actions: {
SetLocale: async (context, payload) => {
  context.commit('SET_LOCALE', payload);
  await setLocale(payload.locale);
},
```

}

then put basic dropdown to navbar or where you want to change language and add method to push new language to store with

```
 methods: {
    async setLocale(locale) {
        await this.$store.dispatch('SetLocale', {
            locale
        });
    },
},
```

than in your app.vue apply the "key" solution above and watch the store data changing

```
<v-main :key="locale">
<transition name="fade-transform" mode="out-in">
    <keep-alive>
        <router-view />
    </keep-alive>
</transition>
```

And add watcher and method to track

```
....... 
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["errors", "locale"])
},
watch: {
    locale: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(newVal, oldVal) {
            this.setLang(newVal)
        },
    },
},
methods: {
    setLang(lang) {
        this.$moment.locale(lang);
        console.log('dil değişti', lang)
    }
},
```

Each time you change i18n lang this will force moment to import new lang and will refresh main component with correct lang.